# How to make notifications using Time in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I have simple app and I want to make the notification by the time 
for example :

I want You reminder me after :
(The user choose) : [ 15 , 30 , 45 , 60 ] Days

if he choosed 30 days then after 30 days he get a notification

Answer (score 1):

I've had good results syncing with the native calendar to push out notifications like like you describe using [react-native-calendar-events.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-events)  Once installed it is simple.  You'd create an event every 30, 60 days.  The 'alarm' calls the native notification system so it does most of the work for you.

```
   RNCalendarEvents.saveEvent('Move Car', {
    startDate: s,
    endDate: e,
    location: l,
    alarms: [{
      date: a
}]
```